# Prefix increments variable twice in C++

Tags: c++, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I'm facing a somewhat classic exam question around postfix and prefix operators, prefix that I can't wrap my head around. Consider the following:

```
#define MAX( a, b ) ( a > b ) ? (a) : (b) 

int main()
{
    int x = 2, y = 2;

    if( MAX( ++x, y ) == x )
    {
        printf( " %d is greater than %d ", x, y );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The exam question asks for the output of the program. To me it would be "3 is greater than 2" but the actual output is **"4 is greater than 2"**

I understand how post and prefix work (or at least I thought so) but I don't get how the variable gets incremented twice. Any explanation on this?

Comment: Yes, don't use macros to avoid confusion.

Comment: Why do this instead of `std::max`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The makro is expanded to

```
( ++x > y ) ? (++x) : (y)
```

There is your double increment.